# Use existing spreadsheet formulas in a custom formula in google docs/spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I like writing my own formulas inside of Google Docs Spreadsheets. But often what I want to do is very similar to **a function that already exists**. As an example, I couldn't find a function to turn a date (31-Aug-2010) into the lexical day of the week (Tuesday). I'd like to write:

```
=LexWeekDay('31-Aug-2010')
'Tuesday'
```

Clearly I can write all of this logic using core javascript, but there already exists a *normal* spreadsheet function called `WEEKDAY()` which [takes a date and converts into into a number representing the day of the week](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155115) `[0 => Sunday, 1=> Monday, etc]`.

**How can I access this function (or generally any function), that speadsheets already define, from my custom script?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell)

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question at [Google help](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?fid=1664806cef0dc29c000498f749f69e1e&hl=en), but did not get a solution. According to user Ahab:

> I understand the need. I voiced the
>   same in the GAS help forum [1](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?fid=1664806cef0dc29c000498f749f69e1e&hl=en) very
>   early one when GAS became available
>   but the reaction from the GAS team was
>   not very promising... :( In essence
>   we'd need a GAS class that contains
>   the spreadsheet functions do allow
>   using them.
>
> Note that in general spreadsheet
>   functions already virtually can be
>   used as a functional programming
>   language without the need of scripting
>   them because of high-level functions
>   like ArrayFormula, FILTER, SORT,
>   UNIQUE, etc.. Unfortunately it is not
>   possible to create e.g. substitution
>   macro's that would allow us to quickly
>   re-use formulas like (in pseudo-macro
>   format):
>
> Name: INVERSE Description: Inverse a
>   columnar array Syntax: #INVERSE( array
>   ) Call: #INVERSE( #1 ) Execute:
>   =ARRAYFORMULA(SORT( #1 ; ROW( #1 ); FALSE))

Answer (score 1):

In your custom appscript, you can use the in-built formulas of google spreadsheet in this way:

Lets say you want to use `=WEEKDAY()` function on cell A1.

Then, get your active spreadsheet like this in your custom appscript function:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("YOUR_SHEET_NAME");
```

now, set the formula like this:

```
sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("=WEEKDAY()");
```

Also, if you want to convert 0,1 etc to Sunday,Monday...then define an array like this:

```
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
```

And then use:

```
var dayIndex = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue(); 
Logger.log(days[dayIndex]);
```

You can see the logs using ctrl+enter or by going to View->Logs in script editor itself.